# Generate random 128 bit number

Tags: c#

I'm working on a school assignement, and one of the requirements is to generate a random 128-bit number.
I'm wondering how to do this in C#, could this method work?

```
byte[] RND128NUMBYTE = new byte[128];
Random Rand = new Random();
Rand.NextBytes(RND128NUMBYTE);
```

Thank you all in advance

**EDIT:** First of all, thank you all for your answers.
Anyway it's better if I clearify the assignement: I'm building a server/client application in a secure way.
After the user connects to the server, to communicate with the other user connected to that server it must be authenticated.User ask auth to the server and the server answer the client with a 128-bit random number. After that some other process will be done.

Comment: That's 128 bytes, not 128 bits.

Comment: 128 bytes exceeds your requirement by a factor of 8.

Comment: Yes `byte[] RND128NUMBYTE = new byte[128**/8**];` would work, but I don't think this is the purpose of your assignment.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thank you for your answer. But i read in the msdn this:"Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.". Does this mean that GUID are generate randomly?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Guids are a source of *uniqueness*, not *randomness*. Yes, some of the bits of a version 4 guid are pseudo-random, but not all of them are. NewGuid is not guaranteed to return a version 4 guid, it's only guaranteed to return a guid. Don't use guids "off label" like this; if you're not using it to guarantee uniqueness, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @Francesco: Version 4 guids are generated pseudo-randomly. See my series of articles on that. http://ericlippert.com/tag/guids/ - start at the bottom.

Comment: And in particular, *even version 4 guids are not a suitable source of entropy to generate bits for crypto purposes*. Again **do not use GUID off-label**, and in general **never use anything for crypto that wasn't designed for crypto**.

Comment: Your auth process smells broken too. A attacker who tries to impersonate the server to the client might be able to ask the server the same challenge and forward the response to the client. For secure network communication you should use SSL/TLS, exposed via the [`SslStream` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) in .net. That does most of the work for you.

Comment: @Francesco - as Eric points out Guids are not appropriate here. I merely mentioned them because your first draft did not specify in what form or for what purpose you needed the number.

Comment: @EricLippert Actually a GUID *might* be fine. It's not clear if the OP needs a crypto strength random number, or if he just needs a nonce. Since GUIDs are unique they're okay as nonces.

Answer (score 13):

The size of an array is given in elements. So for a byte array you need 16 elements with 8 bits each, and not 128 elements.

You can either use `System.Random.NextBytes` or `RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes`.

But `System.Random.NextBytes` is probably not a good choice, since the bad seeding of `System.Random` means you don't get the properties expected of a random 128 bit number. For example you will most likely get collisions even if you generate less than 2^64 numbers. A 128 bit number from a good PRNG is as globally unique as a GUID, one drawn from `System.Random` certainly isn't.

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
using(var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rng.GetBytes(bytes);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

First off, you are generating 128 random bytes, not random bits. But your clarification makes all the difference:

> I'm building a server/client application in a secure way. After the user connects to the server, to communicate with the other user connected to that server it must be authenticated.User ask auth to the server and the server answer the client with a 128-bit random number.

In that case **your solution is deeply, deeply wrong** even after you take into account the fact that you're generating eight times too many bits. `System.Random` is only *pseudo-random*, and **in fact has only 31 bits of entropy when seeded as you are doing**. (*) In order to be secure you need all 128 bits of entropy.

Remember, every missing bit makes the problem half again as easy to attack; if you need 128 bits of entropy and you have 31, then the problem isn't *four* times easier to attack. The problem is 2<sup>128-31</sup> = 10<sup>29</sup> times easier to attack!

Coincidentally I just wrote a blog article about this. I challenged readers to figure out the rest of a deck of cards that I had shuffled with `Random` when given only the first five or six cards. Someone found a solution by brute force in a couple of hours. **Random is extremely weak.**. See http://ericlippert.com/2013/05/06/producing-permutations-part-seven/

If you need crypto strength randomness for a security system then you need to use a special purpose randomness source that has more than 128 bits of entropy in it.

Therefore CodeInChaos's answer is the correct one.

There are two morals of this story:

First, this is why designing security systems is so hard. There are so many details to get right, and you have to get *all* of them right, or the system is not secure.

Second, make sure you give enough information in the question to get a good answer.

---

(*) In fact it has considerably less than that, since some of those 2<sup>31</sup> possible seeds are far more likely than others.

Comment: thank you Eric for your very good comment....I'm moving my first steps into those kind of secure systems so I still a newbie in this. (and alos in c# :D )But anyway I'm reading your blog, very interesting :). You said that the solutions of CodeInChaos is the correct one, and after your explanation I understand why. Thank you both again

Comment: Just one more question, if i want to visualize that number should I use BigInteger? I mean in this way: BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(bytes);. And is this correct if returns a number with - sign?

Comment: @Francesco: You could use BigInteger, sure. However I would be more inclined towards `BitConverter.ToString(byteArray);` See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring.aspx for documentation. Hex strings are usually more useful than decimal when dealing with byte arrays. Also, try to think of the byte array as *a sequence of 128 bits*, rather than as *an encoding of an integer*. If it's not logically being treated as an integer then treat it as bits.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't figuring that out what the assignment is about?

Do like this:
Implement your theory. Run it many many times and store the results. Do some statistics on it like checking for lowest and highest value to know you are inside limits. For extra plus count each result and make sure they are evenly spread.

Answer (score 2):

> the requirements is to generate a random 128-bit number

I think that assignment is a bit too harsh, I hope they mean a [pseudo-random number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_random_numbers_vs._pseudorandom_numbers). I would like to point out you'll have to break problems up into parts you understand.

You've correctly initialized a [PRNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) and know how to let it [fill a byte array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.nextbytes.aspx):

```
Random Rand = new Random();
Rand.NextBytes(RND128NUMBYTE);
```

Now you need to fill a space of 128 bits with randomness. What is 128 bits, does .NET or C# provide you with access to bits? Not directly, but you have a [`byte`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bdb6693%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) type. This type utilizes 8 bits, so you'll only need 128 / 8 = 16 bytes.

You were almost there, you just have to create an array of 16 bytes instead of 128:

```
byte[] RND128NUMBYTE = new byte[16];
```

How to [convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.aspx) these bytes into a "number" I'll let up to you.

Comment: `This stores 128 bits` should be `This stores 8 bits`